# Ajax error with Manage Groups after upgrading to PHP 7.3, MySQL 8.0 and 5.22.0

Tags: groups, ajax, php7, datatables, mysql-8.0

I may have done too many upgrades at once but I was really eager to upgrade my environment following the release of Civi 5.22.0.  I started out with upgrading my Civi Wordpress environment from 5.21.0 to 5.22.0.  I made a backup of my site and database on the old stack.  Then I upgraded my Bitnami stack to PHP 7.3.13 and Mysql 8.0.18.  I performed a data import into the Mysql 8.0 database and everything appeared fine on the surface.

Today I was trying to manage groups that were previously working under the old environment and received an Ajax error (see below).  I have tried deleting all of my groups per recommendations and this did not resolve the issue.  I believe that something may be incorrectly configured within PHP but I'm not sure what it could be.  Can anyone make sense of the error that I am receiving?

Error that occurs when I click on Contacts > Manage Groups within CiviCRM for Wordpress:

```
DataTables warning: table id=DataTables_Table_0 - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7
```

Backtrace:

```
<p>backTrace</p><p><pre>#0 /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(148): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace()
#1 /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src/PEAR.php(922): CRM_Core_Error::handle(Object(DB_Error))
#2 /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB.php(997): PEAR_Error-&gt;__construct(&quot;DB Error: syntax error&quot;, -2, 16, (Array:2), &quot;\n        SELECT groups.*, createdBy.sort_name as created_by \n        FROM  ...&quot;)
#3 /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src/PEAR.php(575): DB_Error-&gt;__construct(-2, 16, (Array:2), &quot;\n        SELECT groups.*, createdBy.sort_name as created_by \n        FROM  ...&quot;)
#4 /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src/PEAR.php(223): PEAR-&gt;_raiseError(Object(DB_mysqli), NULL, -2, 16, (Array:2), &quot;\n        SELECT groups.*, createdBy.sort_name as created_by \n        FROM  ...&quot;, &quot;DB_Error&quot;, TRUE)
#5 /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php(1920): PEAR-&gt;__call(&quot;raiseError&quot;, (Array:7))
#6 /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/mysqli.php(935): DB_common-&gt;raiseError(-2, NULL, NULL, &quot;\n        SELECT groups.*, createdBy.sort_name as created_by \n        FROM  ...&quot;, &quot;1064 ** You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that correspon...&quot;)
#7 /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/mysqli.php(405): DB_mysqli-&gt;mysqliRaiseError()
#8 /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php(1229): DB_mysqli-&gt;simpleQuery(&quot;\n        SELECT groups.*, createdBy.sort_name as created_by \n        FROM  ...&quot;)
#9 /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(2416): DB_common-&gt;query(&quot;\n        SELECT groups.*, createdBy.sort_name as created_by \n        FROM  ...&quot;)
#10 /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(1607): DB_DataObject-&gt;_query(&quot;\n        SELECT groups.*, createdBy.sort_name as created_by \n        FROM  ...&quot;)
#11 /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(420): DB_DataObject-&gt;query(&quot;\n        SELECT groups.*, createdBy.sort_name as created_by \n        FROM  ...&quot;)
#12 /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(1419): CRM_Core_DAO-&gt;query(&quot;\n        SELECT groups.*, createdBy.sort_name as created_by \n        FROM  ...&quot;, TRUE)
#13 /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contact/BAO/Group.php(854): CRM_Core_DAO::executeQuery(&quot;\n        SELECT groups.*, createdBy.sort_name as created_by \n        FROM  ...&quot;, (Array:11), TRUE, &quot;CRM_Contact_DAO_Group&quot;)
#14 /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contact/BAO/Group.php(726): CRM_Contact_BAO_Group::getGroupList((Array:11))
#15 /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Group/Page/AJAX.php(52): CRM_Contact_BAO_Group::getGroupListSelector((Array:11))
#16 /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(234): CRM_Group_Page_AJAX::getGroupList()
#17 /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(68): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:12))
#18 /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(36): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:3))
#19 /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php(1449): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:3))
#20 /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(288): CiviCRM_For_WordPress-&gt;invoke(&quot;&quot;)
#21 /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(312): WP_Hook-&gt;apply_filters(&quot;&quot;, (Array:1))
#22 /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-includes/plugin.php(478): WP_Hook-&gt;do_action((Array:1))
#23 /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-admin/admin.php(254): do_action(&quot;toplevel_page_CiviCRM&quot;)
#24 {main}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL 8 isn't officially supported yet. This particular problem should be fixed in 5.23 though since it's the word "groups" that mysql 8 doesn't like - see https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/1143 and the more general https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/392

Comment: Thank you for the quick response.  I'll roll the environment back to the old stack and try again with 5.23.